# Hive external table location in google cloud storage is ignoring subdirectories

Tags: hadoop, hive, google-cloud-storage, google-hadoop

I have a bunch of large `csv.gz` files in google cloud storage that we got from an external source. We need to bring this in BigQuery so we can start querying but BigQuery cannot directly ingest CSV GZIPPED files larger than 4GB. So, I decided to convert these files into Parquet format and then load in BigQuery.

Let's take example of the `websites.csv.gz` file, which is under path `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/websites/websites.csv.gz`.

Now, for this I wrote a Hive script as below -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE websites (
    col1 string,
    col2 string,
    col3 string,
    col4 string
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 'gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/websites/'
TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1');

msck repair TABLE websites;


CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE par_websites (
    col1 string,
    col2 string,
    col3 string,
    col4 string
) STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/websites/par_websites/';


INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE par_websites
SELECT *
FROM websites;
```

This works well and creates a new folder par_websites as in specified location `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/websites/par_websites/` which has the one parquet file inside it.

But when the `website.csv.gz` file is in a subfolder e.g. `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/data/websites/` and I update the script to have read and write locations as `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/data/websites/` and `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/data/websites/par_websites`, it does not work at all. Hive does not seem to read from `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/data/websites/websites.csv.gz` and instead of creating `par_websites` folder inside `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/data/websites`, it creates a new folder `gs://<BUCKET-NAME>/websites/par_websites` with no parquet file inside.

Why is that and how can I make Hive read and write from subfolders?

Comment: is this working from hdfs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hive was caching my previous table names, so when I was updating it was still showing the older version and not updating.

Once I changed the name and it processed again, all worked well.

Comment: I understand you where able to resolve the issue. Could you add more clarity around the answer so that future visitors find it more helpful? Slightly unclear about the rename operation - did you at some point it time rename the table ?

Comment: Yes, I ran the same exact command but just renamed the table that I was trying to create. This way there was no problem with caches and it worked perfectly. Sorry, I don't have the exact details since it has been a while.